# connection error using googlecite.r

Tags: r

googleCite.r is a great script that I had no problems with about a year ago, but now I get these errors:

I've tried it this way (default instructions in script)

> source("http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~jleek/code/googleCite.r")
>   out <- googleCite("http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=nFW-2Q8AAAAJ&hl=en", pdfname="rafa_cloud.pdf")
>       Error in readLines(con, encoding = "UTF-8") : cannot open the connection

I've also tried with the googleCite package and I get this error:
Error: failed to load HTTP resource

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not a package, it's a sourced, hacked-together script. The initial page took ages to load in the browser, but—even after that—the R script still tosses errors that suggest the format of the page changed. I'm not sure what you need from the page, but you might try extracting components with `rvest` to be a better use of time.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

pg <- html("http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=nFW-2Q8AAAAJ&hl=en")

data.frame(year=pg %>% html_nodes("td.gsc_a_y") %>% html_text(),
           cited_by=pg %>% html_nodes("td.gsc_a_c") %>% html_text(),
           title=pg %>% html_nodes("td.gsc_a_t") %>% html_text())
```